# Separation of concerns for DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance

Now I use Entity Framework with the following DbContext class:

```
public class ItemDbContext : DbContext {
    ...
    public DbSet<Item1> Item1s { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Item2> Item2s { get; set; }
}
```

There are some classes need DbContext with either `Item11s` or `Item2s` as dependencies. So my purpose is create a layer of abstraction for DbContext with that DbSet types (logically separate DbContext_Item1 and DbContext_Item2). It can be useful for implementation of abstract factory pattern (create either DbContext_Item1 or DbContext_Item2 instance) also.

My thoughts:

1) **Interfaces**

```
public interface IDbContext_Item1 { 
    DbSet<Item1> Item1s { get; set; }
}
public interface IDbContext_Item2 { 
    DbSet<Item3> Item2s { get; set; }
}
```

So my abstract factory is able to have API like that:

```
public abstract ItemFactory { 
    public abstract IDbContext_Item1 GetItem1Context;
    public abstract IDbContext_Item2 GetItem2Context;
}
```

It would be fine for me. However class which get IDbContext_ItemX instance doesn't treat it as DbContext instance (i.e. can not call method like SaveChanges() etc.). Unfortunately any interface can not be inherited from class like DbContext.

2) **Extended interfaces** with methods of DbContext

```
public interface IDbContext_Item1 { 
    DbSet<Item1> Item1s { get; set; }
    void SaveChanges;
    // etc
}
```

In my opinion it's extremely not elegant.

3) **Abstract classes** for IDbContext_ItemX

But my current DbContext implementation, `ItemDbContext`, can not be inherited from multiple classes.

4) Just **devide** current `ItemDbContext` on DbContext_Item1 and DbContext_Item2 **concrete classes**.

Yes, it is the decision. But is it only way? It would be great if my concrete factories return instances of `ItemDbContext` under the hood. Can I achieve it?

Comment: What's wrong with having more than one entity in the same DbContext? Unless the two entities are totally unrelated, there is no harm. That is especially true if the two entities are linked with relationships. If you end up with a huge melting pot of 20 entities in the same DbContext, then do something like that, but otherwise, Meh!

Comment: @Tipx it's true for a lot of scenarios, but my idea is SoC. Some class gets an instance of DbContext with the specific types of DbSet through abstract factory. It's great if app has many types of entity and there is a need to devide DbContext on two ones or vice versa from time to times. Then I do not have to rewrite abstract factory API (return types) and  dependencies classes

Comment: Looks to me like you're reinventing the UnitOfWork+Repository pattern. Make sure you know about that first.

Comment: "However class which get IDbContext_ItemX instance ... i.e. can not call method like SaveChanges()" - correct, and it shouldn't. Separation of Concerns, remember?

Answer (score 1):

As I commented, I'd first challenge the reasoning behind wanting to have a single entity for a given context, but if you decide to go forward with that, I'd go with a generic interface, or even a generic context :

```
interface IDbContext<T> where T : class
{
    IDbSet<T> Set { get; }
}

// Context implement generic Interface
class DbContextItem1 : IDbContext<Item1>
{
    IDbSet<Item1> Set { get; private set; }

    override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // Logic to get relevant mappings,
    }
}

// Technically you could also do that.
class DbContextItem1 : IDbContext<Item1>, IDbContext<Item2>
{
    IDbSet<Item1> IDbContext<Item1>.Set { get; }
    IDbSet<Item2> IDbContext<Item2>.Set { get; }

    override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // Logic to get relevant mappings,
    }
}

// Generic context.
class DbContextGeneric<T> : IDbContext<T>
{
    IDbSet<T> Set { get; private set; }

    override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // Logic to get relevant mappings based on T.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create some base interface (lets call it `IDatabaseContext`):

```
public interface IDatabaseContext : IDisposable
{
  //base DbContext stuff like SaveChanges here
}
```

Then you have nested interfaces:

```
IDbContext_Item1 : IDatabaseContext
IDbContext_Item2 : IDatabaseContext
```

And your `ItemDbContext` implements both interfaces.

I agree that writing all `DbContext` methods in `IDatabaseContext` interface is not elegant, but you need to do it just one time